# Need to store "untyped" memory view and cast to typed quickly. Is there an reinterpret_cast equivalent in Cython?

Tags: cython, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast, typed-memory-views

Actually I have a working version of what I need, but it is awfully slow:

```
%%cython -a

cimport numpy as cnp
import numpy as np  # for np.empty

from time import time

cdef packed struct Bar:
    cnp.int64_t dt
    double open
    double high
    double low
    double close
    cnp.int64_t volume

bar_dtype = np.dtype([('dt', 'i8'), ('open', 'f8'), ('high', 'f8'), ('low', 'f8'), ('close', 'f8'), ('volume', 'i8')])

    
cpdef f(Bar bar):
    cdef cnp.ndarray bars_sar
    cdef Bar[:] buffer
    
    bars_sar = np.empty((1000000,), dtype=bar_dtype)
    
    start = time()
    for n in range(1000000):
        buffer = bars_sar
        buffer[0] = bar
        
    print (f'Elapsed: {time() - start}')
    return buffer

def test():
    sar = f(Bar(1,2,3,4,5,6))
    print(sar[0])
    return sar
```

This 1M iterations loop takes about 3 seconds - because of the line takes memory view from numpy structured array:
`buffer = bars_sar`

The idea is that I need `bars_sar` untyped. Only when I want to store or read something from it, I want to reinterpret it as a particular type of memory view, and I don't see any problem why it cannot be done fast, but don't know how to do it. I hope, there is something similar to C reinterpret_cast in Cython.

I tried to declare `bars_sar` as `void *`, but I'm unable to store memory view address there like:

```
    cdef Bar[:] view = np.empty((5,), dtype=bar_dtype)
    bars_sar = <void*>view
```

or even

```
    cdef Bar[:] view = np.empty((5,), dtype=bar_dtype)
    bars_sar = <void*>&view
```

The first one results in error C2440 that it cannot convert "__Pyx_memviewslice" to "void *"
The second one results in error: "Cannot take address of memoryview slice"

Please suggest

Comment: Setting up a memoryview (`buffer = bars_sar`) involves checking that `bars_sar` has the Python protocol, then checking that has the right dimensions and format, as well as acquiring some locks. It's inherently somewhat slow. I think you should explain what you're actually trying to do here, because there's probably a better way than repeatedly setting up a memoryview.

Comment: I'm writing a cdef class that wraps numpy structured array of any dtype allowing to append elements. The array itself is created lazily on append. This way I am able to use fused types in append method. Unfortunately Cython does not support fused typed classes, only methods. So the class instance attribute for array should be somewhat de-typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting my old question, here are 2 ways of achieving what I wanted:

1. Use [Cython.Tempita](https://pyrocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tempita.html) for creating kinda fused class. (I chose this method)
2. Get the pointer to raw data (`&bars_sar[0]`) and work with it directly